# Extending SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have an existing app using single table inheritance:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="entities")
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="class", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "channel" = "Channel",
 *      "aggregator" = "Aggregator"
 * })
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
```

Searching for entities via DQL:

```
$dql = 'SELECT a FROM Volkszaehler\Model\Entity a
```

gets all entities of type `channel` and `aggregator` just fine, this is the SQL that is produced:

```
SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.uuid AS uuid1, e0_.type AS type2, e0_.class AS class6, 
FROM entities e0_ 
WHERE e0_.class IN ('channel', 'aggregator')
```

When I'm trying to extend the inheritance by extending the DiscriminatorMap

```
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "channel" = "Channel",
 *      "aggregator" = "Aggregator",
 *      "generic" = "GenericEntity"
 * })
```

The new `generic` type entites are not found as the SQL remains the same- limiting the query to `channel` and `aggregator`.

I would be thankful for any hint what controls the SQl generation on SINGLE_TABLE inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was caching. The implementation as given above is correct but the metadata was not refreshed (which is confusing as I could *create* the new entity type, but not find it):

```
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
// rebuild cache!
$cache->deleteAll();
```